# Multiple windows in qt QML start flickering / flashing as soon as an animation is run inside any window

Tags: c++, qt, qml, window, flicker

I'm trying to code a prototype for a project of mine that involves multiples windows in a qml based app. Everything works pretty much as intended but when focus changes between windows and an animation is started (in my case it's the default animation inside a quick controls' button) it will start flickering / flashing like crazy.

Notes: I'm currently running Qt 5.13 beta but the problem was already present in Qt 5.12 and we are at only 5 days from the release of Qt 5.13. It is present on both Windows and macOS

Here is a quick demonstration of the problem in a simple exemple, first a gif of the flickering in action when a window focus is resumed and a button clicked (thus an animation is started):

[image: flickering in multiple window exemple]

and the code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
        Button{
            height: 50
            width: 30
        }
    }

    Window {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World 2")
        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "blue"
            Button{
                height: 50
                width: 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and with more advanced  animation, such as this one from my prototype (this is how it should appear without flickering):

[image: normal animation inside main applicationWindow]

but inside a child window, it is simply unusable:

[image: animation flickering inside child qml window]

Thanks for any idea of where is it coming from or any solution !

Comment: I don't see any flickering in the first gif on windows.using `import QtQuick.Controls 2.12` with the provided code.

Comment: I've tested the example on Windows and Ubuntu (both 5.12) and I get no flickering at all. In general, the problem looks like a wrong approach to paint update.

Comment: Thank you both for trying it out on different platforms. I'll reinstall Qt as soon as 5.13 release version is out (may 30th). It may be a bug related to my Qt install ＞︿＜. I'll mark my question as solved if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

After installing the final Qt 5.13 release (not the beta), the problem went away. It was an internal Qt problem I guess.